# Template function parameter and template member function parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I have this problem:

```
template <void (*F)(int)> struct FunctionWrapper // This compiles and works
{
    static void call_it() 
    { 
        F(0); 
    }
};

class MyClass
{
public:
    static void callMe(int k)
    {
    }
};

template <void (MyClass::*F)(int)> struct FunctionWrapper // Error - F incompatible with declaration
{
    static void call_it() 
    { 
        MyClass::F(0); 
    }
};
```

Why I can use a function pointer (compile time constant) but not a class-member (even static) one?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve using your wrapper? Have you considered std::function?

Comment: I'd like to have a class member function in my template's parameter list, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why I can use a function pointer (compile time constant) but not a class-member (even static) one?

You can use a pointer to a static function as a regular function pointer. For instance, the following works:

```
template <void (*F)(int)> struct FunctionWrapper
{
    static void call_it()
    {
        F(0);
    }
};

class MyClass
{
public:
    static void callMe(int k)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    FunctionWrapper<&MyClass::callMe> obj;
    obj.call_it();
}
```

Concerning your attempt, this is what Paragraph 14.1/4 of the C++11 Standard mandates:

> A non-type template-parameter shall have one of the following (optionally cv-qualified) types:
>
> — integral or enumeration type,
>
> — pointer to object or **pointer to function**,
>
> — lvalue reference to object or lvalue reference to function,
>
> — pointer to member,
>
> — std::nullptr_t.

A pointer to *member* function (even if `static`) is not an option for non-type template arguments.

Comment: So a class-member function isn't a compile-time constant? How come? I thought code was shared among all class instances. Perhaps I need at least one instance of a class to have that code available?

Comment: I mean a "non-static" class member function

Answer (score 2):

A static function has the same type signature as a normal function; it is not really a member function.